# Buttons: Tab Order vs Default Property

Tags: ms-access

Create a new form & give it two buttons, make them each popup a window expressing which button you clicked. Select the second button, within its properties on the Other tab change Default to Yes. Run the form, logically the 'Default' button (second one) should be activated when you hit Enter on the keyboard but it isn't. Am I correct that the tab order supersedes the Default property of a button/control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The links below don't explicitly say it, but **note the text in parenthesis**:

> When the command button's Default property setting is Yes and the Form window is active, the user can choose the command button by pressing ENTER (if no other command button has the focus) as well as by clicking the command button.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-a-command-button-the-default-button-in-a-form-or-custom-dialog-box-HP005187773.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/default-property-HA001232729.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837327%28v=office.14%29.aspx